# CSS borders with bezier curves

Tags: css, bezier

We all know it's possible to have rounded corners in plain CSS using the `border-radius` property. Is it also possible to have arbitrary corner shapes, specifically, using `cubic-bezier`?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Have you thought about using SVG?

Comment: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-border-shape/ a lot of other things are available you just have to google it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It most definitely is, by using CSS masking. If you only care about the shape (so, not the color/thickness/etc that you get when you use the CSS `border` property) then setting up a "border shape" is identical to using "a clipping mask", with the kind of shape that is set up by `border-radius` is simply clipping with a "rectangle with rounded corners" mask.

[html5rocks.com](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe) has lots of examples of absolutely crazy border shapes done this way.